# A way to combine 2 seperate queries into one query and 1 table?

Tags: sql

I want to combine 2 separate queries into one query and be able to sort them into 1 table.

This is the code I am wanting to combine

```
SELECT 
    t1.CompanyName as 'Customer Company Name', 
    t1.ContactName, t1.ContactTitle, t1.City, t1.Country, t1.Phone 
FROM 
    Customers t1
WHERE 
    t1.Country = 'Germany'
ORDER BY 
    t1.City;

SELECT 
    t2.CompanyName as 'Supplier Company Name', 
    t2.ContactName, t2.ContactTitle, t2.City, t2.Country, t2.Phone 
FROM 
    Suppliers t2
WHERE 
    t2.Country = 'Germany'
ORDER BY 
    t2.City;
```

I also need to distinguish whether or not they are a supplier or a customer in the table. Is there a way to show where the data for that row came from??

I'm hoping to get something like this

```
Company Name | Contact Name | Phone       | Table of Origin
-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------
Target         Steven        111-111-1111  Customer
Factory Name   Connor        222-222-2222  Supplier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `union all`:

```
SELECT t1.CompanyName, t1.ContactName, t1.Phone, 'Customers' as which
FROM Customers t1
WHERE t1.Country = 'Germany'
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.CompanyName, t2.ContactName, t2.Phone, 'Suppliers' as which
FROM Suppliers t2
WHERE t2.Country = 'Germany';
```

Comment: I got this error: 
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
The multi-part identifier "t2.City" could not be bound.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 44
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: Remove the order by line.

Comment: Thank you very much! :D